# How to find the correct path when creating a virtual environment in python 3

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\Lora\d3stryr-3stripes-master>virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages env
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
```

I have already installed the virtual environment with:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

I'm not sure why it is saying the path does not exist.

Comment: You have to give the full path to the interpreter.

Comment: As far as I understand from your question You have installed _virtualenv_ package. Did you created **virtualenv**?